# Directing robot framework results using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, robotframework

I'm currently using the Eclipse RED plugin for my robot framework automation efforts. How do I direct the test results to a particular folder within my project? When using the terminal, I can direct to the "Results" folder using the following:

```
robot -d Results Tests\MyApp\AppDriverScript.robot
```

However, I'm not sure how to direct the log & report files when using the Eclipse IDE using the Run command (Ctrl+F11).

Answer (score 1):

In the [RED user guide](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/) there is a section about [launching locally](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/launching/local_launch.html).

In the application you want to go to `Run > Run Configurations > Robot` where you add a new Run configuration. Pick the Project, and the proceed to add the Robot Test Suite File and (Optionally) select the keywords to run.

The argument you want to add is indeed `-d Results` in the `Additional Robot Framework Arguments` box. Only this needs to be added, the rest is taken care of by RED.

[image]